# Why is the main menu missing from the screen?

Tags: pokemon-go

My Pokemon Go menu is missing. What can I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting the app, or verify you have a stable internet connection?

Comment: Yes, I've done it, even re-installed the app

Comment: My divice is samsung galaxy a70

Comment: This issue started a few months ago when they released a major update to the UI. The only thing that seems to help is closing and reopening the app. Sometimes it requires clearing the cache before restarting the app. It does seem to be related to connectivity, but on WiFi or cellular it still happens at random. May be Unity-related as Hearthstone has similar rendering-connectivity coupling, but most likely just bad design/programming.